# Class not found at run time though it's in apk file

Tags: android, apk, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to run a program on the phone from android studio. It tries to send an email using javax.mail. When running under the debugger, see these errors in the debug console.

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;
>     at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:261)
>     at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:245)
>     at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:356)
>     at com.example.sendemail.GMailSender.<init>(GMailSender.java:53)
>     ...
>  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger" on path: DexPathList[...]
>     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>     at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:261) 
>     ...
> ```

The class com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger is present in the apk. Found this from 'Analyze APK' (image below). It's in classes.dex. Why isn't it found at run time?

Android Studio version 3.4.1
Android version on phone is 7.0

[image]

Comment: That is a class you probably need to exclude from ProGuard.

Comment: Added **-keep public class com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger** to **app/proguard-rules.pro**, but it did not help.

Comment: Class com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger has 6 referenced methods, so you wouldn't expect it to be removed